# adb "error device not found" when trying to use 'adb shell' but "adb devices" detects the device

Tags: android, bash, terminal, adb

Guys basically I've plugged in a bunch of Android devices to a computer and each of them has `adb` enabled. I'm running a shell script to push certain files to the devices using the Device Serial Numbers stored in a text file. When I trigger the script the first time it works. if i trigger it again `adb` throws an error , `"error device not found"` though the devices are still detected using `adb`. If i close the terminal and reopen it and run the script it works fine. I plan to eventually automate the script running. How can i stop this from happening.

EDIT: This is the piece of code where the adb shell commands are triggered

```
cat device_serial | while read line
do
adb -s $line shell
cd /data/
ls
exit
adb -s $line root
adb -s $line push 'stestfile.txt ' /data/
echo "done"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to look at the script to fix the issue.

But looks like the problem is that the next time you run the script, you are actually in the **device's shell** instead of your computer's.